# login con mysql, jtextfield con datos vacios al realizar consulta

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, login

El problema es este, me he dado cuenta que para cuando hago la consulta a mysql los jtextfield están vacíos aunque ya lo haya llenado en la ejecución del Jframe, entonces a la hora de hacer la consulta.

Me he percatado que **lg.txtUsuario** y **lg.txtPass** ambos están vacíos por lo cual me genera que aunque los datos estén ingresados correctamente, tanto en netbeans como en mysql no me acceda el usuario como debe de ser.

Abajo dejare el código necesario.
Clase de métodos.

```
    Login lg = new Login();
    ConexionMySql sql = new ConexionMySql();

    public int IngresoLogin(){

        String usuario = lg.txtUsuario.getText();
        String pass = String.valueOf(lg.txtPass.getPassword());

        int resultado = 0;

        String SQLConsulta = "SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE usuario=? AND pass=sha1(?)";

        Connection conn = null;

        try{

            conn = sql.conectarMySql();
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(SQLConsulta);
            st.setString(1,usuario);
            st.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){

                resultado = 1;
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex, "Error de conexion",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        }finally{


        try {

            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error de desconexión", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    }
    return resultado;    
    }
```

JFrame Login.

```
private void btnAccederActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Metodos mt = new Metodos();

        if(mt.IngresoLogin()==1){

        this.dispose();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido\n Has ingresado "
        + "satisfactoriamente al sistema", "Mensaje de bienvenida",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        //Formulario1 formformulario1 = new Formulario1();          
        //formformulario1.setVisible(true);

}else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Acceso denegado:\n"
        + "Por favor ingrese un usuario y/o contraseña correctos", "Acceso denegado",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

}
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Dónde agregas los `JTextField` al `JFrame`?

Comment: No entiendo a que parte te refieres, pero los **JTextfield** primero los llamo en una **class** llamada **Metodos** y en el **JFrame Login** llamo a la class Metodo.

Si el resultado del método es igual a **1**, me accedería correctamente, pero como los **JTextfield** están vacíos por la razón que desconozco y no entiendo, aunque la consulta este bien es comparando base de datos con datos vacíos

Comment: Me refiero a que `JFrame` es un contenedor o ventana al cual debes agregar los `JTextField`. En el código no veo dónde agregas los `JTextField` al `JFrame`. Muestra la parte del código donde haces eso.

Comment: Claro, hice eso desde interfaz gráfica si se puede decir así,no estoy creando el **JFrame** con todos sus componentes desde código al 100%, me ayudo de netbeans, para hacer y ordenar los **JTextfield**,**label** y **panel**.

Me he asegurado que los JTextfield sean **public** y que dentro del JTextfield no haya texto,(que este en blanco al ejecutar).